# Oracle Incremental Percent

Tags: oracle11g

i am trying to make a query that return something like this:

```html
<pre>
codigo_vendedor        anio  monto  %inc
100   2014  23   
100   2015  26.50  15.22%
200   2014  20  
200   2015  575  2775.00%
<pre>
```

this is something like incremental percentaje, the problem that i am having is to calculate the %inc column, this is my current query:

```
WITH VENTAS_ANUALES AS (
select 
    c.codigo_vendedor, 
    sum(d.precio*d.cantidad) as monto, 
    extract( YEAR FROM f.fecha) AS ANIO
from detalle d
inner join 
    factura f on f.serie = d.serie and f.numero = d.numero
inner join 
    clientes2 c on c.codigo_cliente = f.codigo_cliente
group by  
    c.codigo_vendedor,
    extract( YEAR FROM f.fecha)
order by c.codigo_vendedor, extract( YEAR FROM f.fecha)
)
SELECT 
VA.CODIGO_VENDEDOR, 
VA.ANIO, 
TO_CHAR(VA.MONTO,'9999.99') AS MONTO,
CONCAT(to_char((VA.monto*100/VA.monto)-100,'9999.99'),'%') AS "%INC" 
FROM VENTAS_ANUALES VA;
```

and actually obviosly i can get all columns, except the incremental percentaje by year:

But i do not know how to calculate the last column.

thank in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a analytic function to get the last MONTO in the same row as the current MONTO like this :

```
LAG(monto) over (PARTITION BY codigo_vendedor ORDER BY anio) AS P_MONTO
```

and put it in a additional outer select :

```
SELECT 
        CODIGO_VENDEDOR
       ,ANIO
       ,MONTO
       ,LAG(VA.MONTO) OVER (PARTITION BY VA.CODIGO_VENDEDOR ORDER BY VA.ANIO) AS P_MONTO
...
```

In the main select add the following expression and alias :

```
SELECT 
       ,VA.CODIGO_VENDEDOR
       ,VA.ANIO
       ,TO_CHAR(VA.MONTO,'9999.99') AS MONTO
       ,((VA.MONTO-VA.P_MONTO)/VA.P_MONTO)*100 || '%' AS "%INC"
...
```

Full query :

```
 WITH VENTAS_ANUALES AS 
   (
        SELECT 
               CODIGO_VENDEDOR
              ,ANIO
              ,MONTO
              ,LAG(VA.MONTO) OVER (PARTITION BY VA.CODIGO_VENDEDOR ORDER BY VA.ANIO) AS P_MONTO
        FROM ( SELECT  C.CODIGO_VENDEDOR
                      ,SUM(D.PRECIO*D.CANTIDAD) AS MONTO 
                      ,EXTRACT( YEAR FROM F.FECHA) AS ANIO
               FROM DETALLE D
               INNER JOIN 
                  FACTURA F ON F.SERIE = D.SERIE AND F.NUMERO = D.NUMERO
               INNER JOIN 
                  CLIENTES2 C ON C.CODIGO_CLIENTE = F.CODIGO_CLIENTE
               GROUP BY  
                  C.CODIGO_VENDEDOR,
                  EXTRACT( YEAR FROM F.FECHA)
             )
    )
    SELECT 
          ,VA.CODIGO_VENDEDOR
          ,VA.ANIO
          ,TO_CHAR(VA.MONTO,'9999.99') AS MONTO
          ,((VA.MONTO-VA.P_MONTO)/VA.P_MONTO)*100  || '%' AS "%INC"
    FROM VENTAS_ANUALES VA
    ORDER BY VA.CODIGO_VENDEDOR, VA.ANIO;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, is correct by the way, i find another way to resolve the problem, but thanks.